# The image did not appear at all

Tags: java, android

the image did not appear at all , there is an exception is always caught by try catch and the image has never been appeared

```
URL url = null;
try {
    url = new URL(currentBook.getImageLink());
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
    bookImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: *there is an exception is always caught by try catch* Which exception??

Comment: I think you are getting `NetworkOnMainThreadException` right? please check this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/6343166/7666442

Comment: Why dont you use glide?

Comment: Why are you performing network operations on the UI thread? Did you read any Android guides?

Comment: thank you Jens.
thank you all commenters , i solved my problem

Comment: @OsamaAldawoody If you solved your problem, then please post your solution as answer and accept it. Accepting your own answer is allowed. This way other users immediately see what solved the problem for you etc.

Comment: it 's not my own answer , i remembered from the comments to use background thread ==> using AsyncTask

Comment: and i used this line of code in mainifest file
==>
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Answer (score 0):

I used this line of code in mainifest file

> android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

and this my code solution using background thread

> private class imageAsyncTask extends AsyncTask{
>    @Override
>        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... url) {
>           if (url.length < 1 || url[0] == null){
>               return null;
>           }
>
> ```
>     URL realyUrl = null;
>     try {
>
>             realyUrl = new URL(url[0]);
>             bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(realyUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
>
>
>     } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
>
>
>     return bmp;
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
>
>     if (bitmap != null){
>
>         bookImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
>     }
> } }
> ```